# Translation of words spoken by King Julien

Tags: translation, madagascar-2

What is the English translation of what King Julien says [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77BOHdscOuY&t=171) from the movie [*Madagascar: Escape 2 Africa*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0479952/)?

The language sounds Russian, but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure which line you're asking about. Are you asking about the line after he asks how is that even possible, or the line after, "Stevie says...?"

Comment: @MattD The Stevie says line ... On my home video, it shows a Russian subtext just for that line.

Comment: Could just be used as a place holder. I'm telling you, he is not saying anything in any actual language. You'd have to post the screen shot for anyone to even begin to help you, and even then it's not a guarantee.

Comment: hmmm that the king for you....."stevie say let eat the cake"

Answer (score 3):

King Julian is not saying anything in any particular language.

If you mean the line after he asks Stevie if that's even possible, all he's saying is, "You naughty little thing," in a very shrill voice.

If you're asking about what he says after the line, "Stevie says," he's simply making a series of noises that is not supposed to be distinguishable. You're not supposed to know what Stevie is saying or what King Julien is *saying* he's saying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm not mistaken, in the actual movie, there are subtitles for what he says after 'You naughty little thing'. I'm not sure exactly what language it's in, but the translation is: "Stevie says ***let them eat cake***". You can find the transcript [here](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/m/madagascar-escape-2-africa-script.html), then scroll down till you reach that part. Or even better, just use control+f, to open the 'find' box, and search 'naughty'. It's the next line after the highlighted one.